# Change style of the data point based on the text area

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented a scatterplot using d3.js v3.

I would like to change the color of the datapoint if for that particular data point annotation has been added.

But when I try to do so, it is changing the color of the first data point in the array instead of the the circle where the annotation has been added.

The way I am implementing is :

```
eventGroup.select("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", 10)
    .attr("cy", 10)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.evtColor ? d.evtColor : "#229ae5";
    })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) {
        return d.evtColor ? d.evtColor : "#229ae5";
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .on("contextmenu", function(d) {
        var position = d3.mouse(this.parentNode);
        d3.event.stopPropagation(); // to avoid over-ridding of click event on the chart background
        d3.select("#context-menu")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 220) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 70) + "px")
            .style("display", "inline-block")
            .on("click", function() {
                d3.select("#context-menu").style("display", "none");
                d3.select("#annotateBox")
                    .style("position", "absolute")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 220) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 70) + "px")
                    .style("display", "inline-block");
                d3.select("#eventLabel").text(d.label);
                d3.select("#eventTime").text(d.time);
                d3.select("#textArea").node().value = d.textArea || "";
                d3.select("#done").on("click", function() {
                    d.textArea = d3.select("#textArea").node().value;
                    d3.select("#annotateBox").style("display", "none");
                    if (d.textArea) {
                        d3.select("circle.dot").style("fill", "#ed6a1c");
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

I cannot do `d3.select(this.parentNode)` as the parent element is not the circle.dot. What element should be selected in order to change the color of datum where annotation text has been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the clicked DOM element (i.e., the circle)...

```
.on("contextmenu", function(d) {
    var thisCircle = this
    etc...
```

And use it afterwards:

```
if (d.textArea) {
    d3.select(thisCircle).style("fill", "#ed6a1c");
}
```

Comment: aah! this was pretty straight-forward. Thanks :)